# How to create Eigen::Ref to RowMajor Matrix objects?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am finding it difficult to take references to matrix objects like blocks or vector with `Eigen::RowMajor` storage order.

I have usecases where I want a reference to the vector representation of a matrix (using `reshaped`) or the block of the matrix. In all these usecases I want the matrix to be in row major order (`Eigen::RowMajor`) is required.

The default column-major order in the following code works for reshaping and blocks:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{

    Eigen::MatrixXf mat(5,6);

    mat << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
        7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
        13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
        19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
        25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 ;

    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXf> mat_ref_vect = mat.reshaped() ;

    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXf> mat_ref_block = mat.block(0, 0, 2, 6) ;
}
```

However, the following doesn't work when the storage order is changed to `Eigen::RowMajor`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{

    Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> mat_row_major(5, 6) ;
    mat_row_major << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
        7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
        13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
        19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
        25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 ;

    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXf> mat_row_major_ref_vect = mat_row_major.reshaped<Eigen::RowMajor>() ;

    Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXf> mat_row_major_ref_block = mat_row_major.block(0, 0, 2, 6) ;

}
```

So, what changes should I make to create a reference to the `RowMajor` object. I believe the `InnerStride` is matching in the second case but I might be wrong.

Comment: You didn't specify what element order you want. However, `mat_row_major.transpose().reshaped()` compiles and gives the order `[1, 2, 3, …]`

Comment: I have added more details to the original post. I want to take reference to parts of the matrix. But I want the row major ordering of the matrix.

Comment: You cannot create a mutable reference of a matrix reshaped into a vector if there are any gaps within. Mutable `Ref` is basically the same an `Eigen::Map`, so for vectors it holds a start pointer and a size, plus optionally an inner stride. In a row-major matrix block, if the stride from one row to the next is different from the stride between columns, it cannot be mapped in this way without a copy.

Comment: As a more general note, in my experience, overusing `Ref` as a general cure-all for data typing is dangerous. `Ref` is designed only for function arguments, nothing more. Taking it out of that role is a recipe for dangling pointers, unintended overwrites, and hidden data copies.